# Invalid Column name and The multi-part identifier could not be bound in WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get the code below to work. My particular issue is when I add "gh" and "rn" in the last WHERE clause I get back either "Invalid column name" or "The multi-part identifier could not be bound" in all my attempts. Here is where the query stands at the moment. Any thoughts?

```
SELECT T.customer_no,
       ref_no,
       cont_dt,
       cont_amt,
       cust_type,
       rn,
       gh
FROM   (SELECT customer_no,
               ref_no,
               cont_dt,
               cont_amt,
               cont_type,
               rank()
                 OVER(
                   partition BY customer_no
                   ORDER BY T_contribution.cont_amt DESC) AS gh,
               row_number()
                 OVER(
                   partition BY customer_no
                   ORDER BY T_contribution.cont_amt DESC) AS rn
        FROM   T_contribution
        WHERE  cont_dt <= '2015-12-31') AS T
       INNER JOIN (SELECT customer_no
                   FROM   T_CONTRIBUTION
                   GROUP  BY customer_no
                   HAVING count(cont_dt) > 1) grouped
               ON T.customer_no = grouped.customer_no
       INNER JOIN T_CUSTOMER
               ON T.customer_no = T_CUSTOMER.customer_no
WHERE  ( cust_type = '1'
          OR cust_type = '3'
          OR cust_type = '7' )
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM   T_contribution AS t2
                       WHERE  T.customer_no = t2.customer_no
                              AND t2.gh <> 1
                              AND t2.rn <> 2)
ORDER  BY T.customer_no
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand exactly the logic of your query but it looks that you are using the wrong alias with the columns "gh" and "rn" that come both from the nested query aliased T.

Your last WHERE clause should be:

```
WHERE cust_type IN ('1', '3', '7' ) AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM   T_contribution AS t2
    WHERE  T.customer_no = t2.customer_no
    AND T.gh <> 1
    AND T.rn <> 2 ) ORDER  BY T.customer_no
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    select customer_no, ref_no, cont_dt, cont_amt, cont_type,
    rank() over(partition by customer_no order by T_contribution.cont_amt desc) as gh,
    row_number() over(partition by customer_no order by T_contribution.cont_amt desc) as rn
    from T_contribution
    where cont_dt <= '2015-12-31'
)
select T.customer_no, ref_no, cont_dt, cont_amt, cust_type, rn, gh 
from DataSource T
inner join
(
    SELECT customer_no
    FROM T_CONTRIBUTION
    GROUP BY customer_no
    having count(cont_dt) > 1
) grouped
    ON T.customer_no = grouped.customer_no 
inner join T_CUSTOMER 
    on T.customer_no = T_CUSTOMER.customer_no
where (cust_type='1' or cust_type='3' or cust_type='7') 
    and not exists 
    (
        select 1 
        from DataSource as t2 
        where T.customer_no = t2.customer_no 
            and t2.gh <> 1and t2.rn <> 2
    )
order by T.customer_no
```

You are not allowed to use ranking functions like `RANK` and `ROW_NUMBER` directly in the `WHERE` clause. That's because they are calculated in the `SELECT` phase, which is executed in after the `WHERE` one. So, you just need to wrapped them in common table expression (for example) and then to refer them in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: That worked! But why (so that I know for next time)?

Comment: Appreciate the explanation!